JavaFX not rendering properly on Raspberry Pi (aarch64)
We are trying to port a library of jars using JavaFX from Windows, where they currently run, to linux / aarch64.
Goal:
is to get them running on off the shelf ARM hardware, i.e. Raspberry Pi. (ideally with minimum modifications, as we need to support the legacy windows platform as well)
Actual behavior
We tested in 2 steps, x86_64 used as proof of concept the GUI is working on linux. aarch64 target is a Raspberry Pi 4B.
Erroneous behavior:

custom controls not displaying at all -> black / blank window
Images and text display, but position and scaling is off.
Animations (i.e. image fade-in) not working

This behavior was observed with older versions on x86_64 as well, appearing visually identical to aarch64 on all versions.
All versions tested with SDKs including JavaFX from: openjdk/openjfx, temurin, gluon, azul zulu



SDK version
x86_64
aarch64




24ea
OK
failed


23.0.1
OK
failed


22
OK
failed


21
OK
failed


17
failed
failed



Expected behavior
Proper rendering of GUI on aarch64.
I know that aarch64 is not officially supported for JavaFX - yet the new MacBooks use that architecture and there are some bugs listed on the openjdk bugtracker.
This is why I'd assume, that it should work in principle, and why I suspect something wrong with my setup or the specific platform i.e. RPi 4B.
Questions

Has anyone experienced similar problems, that might offer some insight in what is happening here?

How to debug this issue?
-Dprism.debug=true -Dprism.verbose=true does not tell me much, except graphics pipeline is falling back to sw

Anything that we can try besides what we already did?


